# Hide products which are not related to category selection (search filter)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a drop down search filter that narrows down the users search by product category, For example if they select burgers, burgers will show.

My search filter works perfectly as its shows the correct products. But even after selecting the category, the categories products show at the top of the page, and all the other products can be seen at the bottom of the page, my question is how would i go around hiding the products that are not in the selected category.

For example only showing the products from burgers and nothing else.

My code for the products page, is on a separate file from the code for the search filter page(getcats.php) , however, they share the exact same query for getting the products. The Search filter page is included in the products page :

**Code**

*Search filter page*

```
   $cats = intval($_GET['cat']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Rest_Category
        INNER JOIN Rest_Details
        ON Rest_Category.CategoryID = Rest_Details.Cat_ID
                    WHERE Rest_Category.CategoryID   = '" . $cats . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

    while ($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $rest_id = $row_cats['Resturant_ID'];
    $rest_name = $row_cats['Resturant_name'];
   echo '<p>$rest_id</p>' .
        '<p>$rest_name</p>' .;
      }
    }
```

*Products page*

```
function showCat(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getcats.php?cat="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
      }
   }
```

HTML

```
 <div id="txtHint"><b></b></div>
```

Comment: Add sample data also, and what you are getting vs what you expect.

Comment: The code you have shared does not show why it should work like you describe.

Comment: @trincot i am looking for guidance, like suggestions on how to move forward

Comment: All I can say is that there is no way the `SELECT` statement can produce anything else than products with the category id passed to it. It is probably other code that is being executed. Just debug your code. Put `echo` and `print_r` at different places to see what is happening.